# ANTLR4 build runtime from source without nuget

Tags: c#, antlr4

I tried to build the current ANTLR 4 csharp target taken from [here](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/releases/tag/v4.3.0). 
VS2013 tells me that i'm missing the Antlr4.4.2.1-alpha001 package when building.
I need a previous version of the runtime to build the current runtime?
Presumably i missed something but what? Is there some documentation on how to build it if its not just opening the solution and hitting build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project is configured to automatically download missing dependencies during the build. However, NuGet is currently limited in its ability to download dependencies which involve a custom ***.targets** file which is [referenced by the project](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/30b8b1452ddc6435f6968d988a4e136465468a9a/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/Antlr4.Runtime.net45.csproj#L254). To build a solution with such a dependency, you'll need to take the following steps:

1. Right click the solution in **Solution Explorer** → **Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...**
2. If a bar appears at the top of the dialog indicating that one or more required packages are currently missing, click **Restore**.
3. Restart Visual Studio (or close and reopen the solution).

The C# Runtime for ANTLR 4 uses this dependency for both the ["XPath" support](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs/blob/master/runtime/CSharp/Antlr4.Runtime/Tree/Xpath/XPathLexer.g4) and portions of the testing library.

**Note:** This answer covers only your specific question about missing packages. The build process for the referenced project is not documented, and likely requires additional steps which are not described here.

Comment: Thanks. I had a nuget.config in place that moved the packages folder away. The ANTLR Solution seems to not like that (they get downloaded there but then they can't be found afterwards). Putting back the packages folder in the default spot, restoring the packages as you write, and uncheck signing works.